# Is it possible to run browsers in headless mode in a windows box?

Tags: webdriver, headless-browser

I'm writing tests using webdriver in Java. 
Is there a way to run browsers (ff / ie) in headless mode in a windows box?

I cant use a linux box and HtmlUnitDriver is not helping as our webapp has many ajax controls.

Comment: The ajax result of HtmlUnitDriver is quite different with normal browser(FF, Chrome etc.) If your site is a heavy ajax site, you'd better not employ HtmlUnitDriver.

Answer (score 2):

I have started a small project to supply a driver for WebDriver using SimpleBrowser. You may want to check it out: https://github.com/Teun/SimpleBrowser.WebDriver

It's still early days though. I would appreciate help in the form of contributions and testing.

Answer (score 1):

At this point there is no headless version that I am aware of the Firefox or IE.  Since Firefox is open source it's possible that you could get the source code for that browser and then remove the UI portion but there are a few problems with it that I can see.  First you have to build a custom app to setup your own load testing engine.  Second you are locked to one web render, though I think chrome is open source as well but it doesn't play as nicely as Firefox or IE (using the system .dlls vs. a custom executable).  Third without a lot of testing I am sure there will be stability issues and potentially other unforseen issues with this option.  That being said there is a .net headless browser that's fairly simple and would probably be decent for load testing called simple browser.  However it depends on what you are wanting to load.  If you just looking for bandwidth and server load then you should be find using multiple instances of the browser.  I would be curious to know if using the headless browser in this fashion if you instantiated different WebDriver if it would play nicely. i.e.

```
WebDriver driver1 = new SimpleBrowser();
WebDriver driver2 = new SimpleBrowser();
.
.
.
.
.
WebDriver driver[n] = new SimpleBrowser();
```

and then you could run [n] parallel tests.  Also of note in the above code SimpleBrowser() doesn't hook directly to the WebDriver interface you would have to Extend the interface to reference that .dll

Comment: SimpleBrowser is awesome, I've used it for load testing and it works wonderfully. It does not support Javascript or Ajax however, so it might not work in this instance...

Comment: @Anders ah yes I forgot about that.  The flip side is that the SimpleBrowser is open source so if you are feeling frisky and really want it to work you could always build in your support of javascript and ajax

Comment: I've been wanting to do that for a while... but where to find the time? :)

Answer (score 0):

Start the test program as a Windows service and the browsers will run just fine, even on a machine with no monitors.  Technically speaking, they're running in a "session" that is disconnected, but it's essentially what you mean by "headless".

Comment: That's not the same thing at all. Headless means that no time is spent rendering the webpage visually (even if you can't see it because there is no monitor) which consumes far fewer resources, which in turn means that tests run a lot faster.  If you've ever tried to run multiple tests in parallel (such as for a load test) you would know the value of a truly headless browser.

Comment: Is it also possible to use selenium grid ("selenium node") as a service on Windows and have it launch browsers (IE in particular) on demand, without any login required)? How can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

HtmlUnitDriver does support ajax, and can run in both java and c# (if ported via IKVM).
There is, however, no way to run IE and FF in headless mode.  I can't tell you how many times I've wished for that...

Comment: Thx for confirming it. Limitations of HtmlUnitDriver is the reason for us start using FF driver.

Comment: IE and Firefox run just fine in headless mode.